# Use javascript to change the href of a button depending on screensize

Tags: javascript

I made a fluid grid based website, and now i want to add movie content within an iframe. Since the iframe is changeing size, i made the content i want to add in these 3 sizes:

-option1 size: 720p: 1280 x 720
-option2 size: 480p: 854 x 480
-option3 size: 360p: 640 x 360

now i'm looking for a script to measure the screen of the user, and then to change the href of the button to option 1, 2 or 3.

This is how far i come. i hope someone has an example.

```
<a target="iframe_cinema" onclick="myFunction() href="option1" id="window"  class="button2 white">
            <img src="images/3D.png"</div></a>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

var x=window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;


if (Width<640)
  {
  x="option1";
  }
else if (Width<854)
  {
  x="option2";
  }
else
  {
  x="option3";
  }

</script>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option. Use media queries and show/hide buttons based on the size.

**CSS Media Way**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

        @media screen {
            #div3{ display : block; }
            #div1, #div2{ display : none; }
        }        


        @media screen and (max-width:800px) {
            #div2{ display : block; }
            #div1, #div3{ display : none; }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width:400px) {
            #div1{ display : block; }
            #div2, #div3{ display : none; }
        }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="div1">ONE</div>
      <div id="div2">TWO</div>
      <div id="div3">THREE</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript way you were doing:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#option1" id="myLink">LINKY</a>
    <script>    
        (function(){    
            var link = document.getElementById("myLink");    
            function checkWidth() {
                var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth,
                    newHref;
                if (width<640) {
                  newHref="#option1";
                } else if (width<854) {
                  newHref="#option2";
                } else {
                  newHref="#option3";
               }
               link.href=newHref;       
            }
            link.onclick = checkWidth;
            checkWidth();
        })();          
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awsome! I used the second option and it works perfect. i hope i dont ask too much, but is it possible to add the interval so he keeps checking on width after people clicked the button and then change treir screen size? Thanks lot!

Comment: bind to the window resize event, but is it needed with the onclick event?